# Powerbi & Google sheet real time sync

Tags: google-sheets, powerbi

I'm trying to make a **live connection** between power bi and google sheet with the following code link from Google sheet created in Power Bi desktop

[Google sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vT0qr86M228TM4cu6yYvLJcjkanWrGWM8dbPi_hp0avTYX6bkGM7PRn0E0_Tntx-Iy2aS1cWXzneh0N/pub?output=csv)

I have successfully connected and published the report to the web in Power Bi services

[Power bi published link](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiYmViZWVlZDktZDNlOC00MjRmLWE3YzgtMTJkMzFlNzFhNDk4IiwidCI6IjYxNWFjY2ZiLTU0ZjMtNGFmOS05ZjQ0LTgwM2Y0Mzc5ZTRjOCIsImMiOjl9)

But I want the Power Bi to synchronize very often (Once in a half hour will be fine). Is it possible? I am using the free Power Bi services version

I am aware of the dialog for refreshing but it looks to apply once a day only

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Power BI limits automatic refreshes per 24h to 1 for Free, 8 for Pro and 48 for Premium.

Quote from [Data refresh in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data#data-refresh):

> Power BI limits datasets on shared capacity to **eight** daily refreshes. If the dataset resides on a Premium capacity, you can schedule up to **48 refreshes** per day in the dataset settings.

This means that if you want to refresh your imported dataset every 30 minutes, you need to buy a dedicated capacity for your workspace (i.e. Power BI Premium or Power BI Embedded), or to change your report to use DirectQuery and move your data to a [supported data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-data-sources).

And another important quote from the docs, that you should be aware of:

> Note also that the configured refresh time might not be the exact time when Power BI starts the next scheduled process. Power BI starts scheduled refreshes on a best effort basis. The target is to initiate the refresh within 15 minutes of the scheduled time slot, but a delay of up to one hour can occur if the service can't allocate the required resources sooner.